# UDF aberrant behaviour

Tags: sql, ado.net, toad

I am accessing a UDF through code and through toad.
It always throws error through toad but shows random behavior in code(Sometime it works sometime it doesn't).

```
SELECT ADD_DEFAULT_MEASURES(:pModule, :pSummarySourceTypeId) FROM DUAL
```

Steps(In code):

1. module = 'aut' and summary source = 244 - throws error(ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back)
2. change summary source to 56.
3. module = 'aut' and summary source = 56  - works
4. change summary source back to 244.
5. module = 'aut' and summary source = 244 - works

Through Toad

1.module = 'aut' and summary source = 56  - works

2.module = 'aut' and summary source = 244 - throws error(ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back)

Why is it showing random behavior when executed through code ?